# i have a external api using that i want to login wordpress

Tags: php, javascript

```
function custom_login_authentication($username, $password) {
    // Set API endpoint URL
    $url = "https://webapi.barecms.com/api/users/login";
    
    $data = array(
        'email' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    );
    
    $json_data = json_encode($data);

    // Initialize cURL session
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close cURL session
    curl_close($ch);

    // Handle the API response
    $response_data = json_decode($response, true);
    var_dump($response_data);
    var_dump($user);


    if ($response_data && isset($response_data['success']) && $response_data['success'] === 1) {
        // User login is successful, log them into WordPress
        $user = get_user_by('email', $username);
        
        if ($user) {
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);
            wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $username);
            do_action('wp_login', $username);
        }
    } else {
        // User login failed, handle the error
        $error_message = "Invalid username or password.";
        wp_redirect(wp_login_url() . '?login=failed&message=' . urlencode($error_message));
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('wp_authenticate', 'custom_login_authentication', 20, 2);

function custom_login_failed($username) {
    $referrer = wp_get_referer();

    // Redirect back to the login page with an error message
    wp_redirect(add_query_arg('login', 'failed', $referrer));
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_login_failed', 'custom_login_failed');
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/416302/edit) to let us know what *specific* problem you're having. What's the expected outcome? What's not working? Do you get any errors? Code-only questions aren't really questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.